# What is the typography of the original coexist symbol?

Tags: fonts, typography, icon

The coexist symbol has become more or less widespread. I'd like to know:

#### Which is the font used by the original designer: [Piotr Mlodozeniec](https://youtu.be/Zm6na9tz4-s?t=28)?

[image: Coexist logo]

I'm surprised that an icon has become popularized only after being changed from the original.

Comment: I believe the reason the altered icon became far more widespread than the original is because it was changed to incorporate many more religious and other symbols, making it applicable to a broader audience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is Geometric 415 Black
https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/tilde/geometr-415/black/

You can see the distinctive angling of the N and curves of the S.

[image]